# In Avro (1.8.0) IDL, can I make an array<string> generate as a java.util.HashSet?

Tags: java, code-generation, maven-plugin, avro, idl

I'm generating records using Avro IDL.

Setting my String types to String and setting fieldVisibility to PRIVATE, with this input:

```
record MyRecord {
        @java-class("java.util.HashSet")  array<string> flagged;
}
```

Avro generates

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class MyRecord extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7930925833711109001L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"MyRecord\",\"namespace\":\"com.example\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"flagged\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"},\"java-class\":\"java.util.HashSet\"}}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
   private java.util.List<java.lang.String> flagged;
```

I expected:

```
   private java.util.HashSet<java.lang.String> flagged;
```

Is it possible to make an `array` work with Set semantics?